# How To Open The Comment Form In Modal Form

Tags: 7, comments, chaos-tool-suite, rating, javascript

I want To Provide The Link "Add Reviews" For Content Type Example "Doctor". Then How I can Use the Comment Functionality For That. So that When the user Click on the Add reviews Link A modal Form  Appears  Having Text Field with "Rating Star". so that user can submit Reviews For that Content Type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Colorbox Node](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node).

So you should have this link in your node.tpl.php:

```
print l(t('Review'), 'comment/reply/' . $nid . '?width=600&height=600', array(
          'attributes' => array(
            'class' => array('colorbox-node')
                )));
```

Comment: I want to use APIs of Ctools and Modal Form Module for Same Functionality.